# use react-redux with connect() and {...this.props}

Tags: reactjs, nested, redux, react-redux

I cannot figure out, how to make right solution, when I want to call action in my container from other component, by the way I want to use spread operator because I need to pass too many parametrs in my component and don't want describe all of them.

I know I can pass all props from redux store via props, like this example in Menu, but my component too nested, and I have to send props in eighter component in nest

```html
render() {

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Menu {...this.props} />
            </div>
        );

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = reduxStore => (
    {
        app: reduxStore.app
    }),

    mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({appActions: bindActionCreators(appActions, dispatch)});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

So, I decided to connect my nested component with redux store, because I need to work from my nested component with store and actions in main container component. But this solution doesn't work, because i use spread operator to my nested component.

```html
render() {

        return <Link activeClassName='active' onClick={this.props.appActions.closeMenu} {...this.props} />;

    }
```

And using spread operator is really important because component get too much different parameters from its parent component, and if i don't use {...this.props}, I have to write like this:

```html
render() {

        const { to, onlyActiveOnIndex, className, specialIcons } = this.props;

        return <Link activeClassName='active' onClick={this.props.appActions.closeMenu} to={to} specialIcons={specialIcons} onlyActiveOnIndex={onlyActiveOnIndex} className={className} >{this.props.children}</Link>;

    }
```

But also, I have to connect to common redux store, and when I connected, occurs an Error, because of my component use {...this.props} and it get all props, including actions from container and component doesn't know what do with them. I find one solution of this proplem, but I'm not sure that it is right variant. I clone props with spread operators, but delete property that contain new functions (actions) from common store.

```html
render() {

        let oldProps = {...this.props};
        delete oldProps.appActions;
        delete oldProps.app;

        return <Link activeClassName='active' onClick={this.props.appActions.closeMenu} {...oldProps} >{this.props.children}</Link>;

    }

}

const mapState = reduxStore => ({app: reduxStore.app}),
    mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({appActions: bindActionCreators(appActions, dispatch)});

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatchToProps)(NavLink);
```

I'm guessing that I don't understand something basic and global in react-redux or I use bad practice. May be I should use higher order components in React? but now I don't know how to make it better.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a functional example. I made it for a personal project. I removed the useless code for the purpose of the example.
Something you might want to get is eslint, it will show you basic mistake people are making while coding.

For example, it will say that you having declared your PropTypes. In your code, where does it say what app is? Sure it's coming from reduxStore.app but what kind of PropTypes is it?

Also, you shouldn't link all the reduxStore state to your component. You should just import what you really need. In my example, I import only `users` from `state.app.users`. If I had more, or want all elements of the reducer state, I would import all of them individually and then declare the props like this:

```
 Home.propTypes = {
        users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        actions: {
            load: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        },
    };
```

Because JavaScript isn't a typed language, the PropTypes like above help you make typed validation. You can also see the props `actions` which contains all the functions you import in `AppActions` in your case.

To see how to use the function from the action afterward, look at my `componentWillMount()`

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { ListView} from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

    import * as app from '../../actions/appActions';

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    class Home extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(props.users.toJS()),
            };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            this.props.actions.load();
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if (this.props.users !== nextProps.users) {
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(nextProps.users),
                });
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                  <ListView
                      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                      enableEmptySections
                      renderRow={
                          (rowData) => <User haveLunch={rowData.haveLunch} name={rowData.name} />
                      }
                  />
            );
        }
    }

    Home.propTypes = {
        users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        actions: {
            load: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        },
    };

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            users: state.app.users,
        };
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            actions: bindActionCreators(app, dispatch),
        };
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Hope this will help ya ;)